# Table in Overlay in SAP-UI5

Tags: json, html, overlay, sapui5

I'm new to SAP UI5, I have a requirement to create overlay on click of a button. The Overlay contains a table and table is populated from JSON.

I looked at this [Fullscreen Overlay Control for OpenUI5](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/05/10/fullscreen-overlay-control-for-openui5). But, I'm unable to put a table in the overlay.

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I checked [the link](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/05/10/fullscreen-overlay-control-for-openui5/) you have given. Custom controller has been used in that example. As that kind of control is not defined by SAP UI5 out of the box:

- Use this to make overlay container --> https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.ux3.OverlayContainer
- Use this to make table with bindings --> https://ui5.sap.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table
- And then do `oOverlayContainer.addContent(objTable)`.